# loop on object angular 4 and lodash typescript error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I create simple loop on object in my pipe:

```
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
      let room;
      _.forEach(this.rooms,function (el,index) {
          console.log(el);
          if(el.id == value){
            room == el;
          }
      });
      return room;
  }
```

I can see on console that my object "el" has property id inside but i cant check it. I use lodash library to loop but i get error : " Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'."

How can I avoid this do i have to create double loop to access one property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use arrow function and see

```
_.forEach(this.rooms,(el: any) =>{
        console.log(el);
        if(el.id == value){
          room == el;
        }
    });
```